Writing asynchronous code without asyncio
I'm trying to write code that is the equivalent of the busy loop
async def wait_for_callback():
    while True:
         <do some work>
         if <callback has occurred>
              return <result>
         await asyncio.sleep(0)

However this is intended to be a library routine, and I do not know which asynchronous library the user is using.  I know that I could use anyio.sleep if I believe the user is going to be using trio or asyncio, but I also know those aren't the only asynchronous libraries out there.
Is it possible to write the equivalent of await asyncio.sleep(0) while remaining completely agnostic as to the which asynchronous library is being used?

Unfortunately, no. Tasks are wrappers for coroutines, and those are just slightly modified generators. Asynchronous code works by sending some objects from the coroutine to the event loop via internal yield, and the processing of these objects is written at the level of the asynchronous library, for which there are no standards.
Here's asyncio.sleep() from Python 3.13:
async def sleep(delay, result=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay <= 0:
        await __sleep0()
        return result

    if math.isnan(delay):
        raise ValueError("Invalid delay: NaN (not a number)")

    loop = events.get_running_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    h = loop.call_later(delay,
                        futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                        future, result)
    try:
        return await future
    finally:
        h.cancel()

This function creates an asyncio-specific future, which is then yielded into the event loop (await future is actually yield future). No other asynchronous library understands asyncio futures.
Moreover, other libraries also use their own mechanisms. For example, Trio 0.27.0 uses move_on_at() + wait_task_rescheduled(), which means that an object of the WaitTaskRescheduled class is yielded. And Curio 1.6 yields a tuple. Thus, neither sleep() is compatible with the other.
The 0 second sleep case you are asking for is usually handled in a special way, but still has no compatibility. asyncio yields None, which only it supports, Trio still yields its own objects, and Сurio does not handle this case in a special way at all.
If you want an efficient solution, you can write your own sleep() using sniffio. You'll have to manually write a case for each library, but there's no other way. Here's an example of how you can do this with lazy imports:
from sniffio import current_async_library


async def asyncio_sleep(seconds):
    global asyncio_sleep

    from asyncio import sleep as asyncio_sleep

    await asyncio_sleep(seconds)


async def curio_sleep(seconds):
    global curio_sleep

    from curio import sleep as curio_sleep

    await curio_sleep(seconds)


async def trio_sleep(seconds):
    global trio_sleep

    from trio import sleep as trio_sleep

    await trio_sleep(seconds)


async def sleep(seconds):
    library = current_async_library()

    if library == "asyncio":
        await asyncio_sleep(seconds)
    elif library == "curio":
        await curio_sleep(seconds)
    elif library == "trio":
        await trio_sleep(seconds)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f"unsupported async library {library!r}")

    # You can also replace if-elif-else with fast match-case if you don't need
    # Python 3.9 support.

In a perfect world, we could write something like this:
@types.coroutine
def sleep(seconds):
    return (yield seconds)

But unfortunately, event loops don't understand numbers.

Thanks. The more I looked into it, the more I was sure the answer was going to be "No".  I appreciate the extended explanation.
